# IntelliJ IDEA - different "targets"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project (maven + spring + hibernate) for a web app. I'm no pro at Java and I'm wondering if there's a way to use the same project for another app. The two version would share a lot of code, but there will be some unique classes and functions. Ideally, when I'll make a change in one shared functions, I won't have to manually edit both projects.

I'm a iOS Developer and usually I use macros for this purpose (here's explained in detail http://www.itexico.com/blog/bid/99497/iOS-Mobile-Development-Using-Xcode-Targets-to-Reuse-the-Code):

```
#if APP1
#define SERVER_URL @"http://server.com/green/"
#define PROJECT_NAME @"GREEN APP"
#else
#define SERVER_URL @"http://server.com/yellow/"
#define PROJECT_NAME @"YELLOW APP"
#endif
```

Is there any way to do something like this in Java using IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned Maven, I guess the best would be using your build tool rather than IntelliJ idea as you mention in a question.

So in Java you might want to create an "infrastructure" module that would contain all the "shared" functionality. This module will by built into a dedicated jar by Maven.

Then in all your project you'll just include this module as a Maven dependency tag like this:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>,,,,</groupId>
     <artifactId>youSharedModuleName</artifactId>
     <version>...</version>     
 </dependency>
```

That's the easiest way. After all, in run-time JAR is nothing more than a container for you classes that Java can handle transparently for you.

Now you can keep this infrastructure as a completely separated project in your source control system so that you'll be able to release it independently of your main project jars buts its a different story.